# Where can I find software images for shortcuts

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am creating desktop shortcuts on Ubuntu and I did the whole process of finding the executable in the applications folder then copying them to desktop and finally right clicking and allowing them to be launched. The problem I have is that the shortcut has no image. On windows I would easily go to the installed path of the program and find its image but on Linux I have no idea where I can find those files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First search the package of your executable

```
dpkg -S  /full/path/to/executable
```

Then list that package's contents, see if it contains icons.

```
dpkg -L packagename
```